# How can I avoid accessing private members of a class using Reflection?

Tags: c#, security, reflection

I was reading [Security Considerations for Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and I saw the following line:

> Transparent code cannot use reflection to access security-critical members, even if the code is fully trusted. A MethodAccessException, FieldAccessException, or TypeAccessException is thrown.

So, I've written a test program:

Class Library:

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public class Foo
    {
        [SecurityCritical] private int X;
    }
}
```

Test program:

```
using ClassLibrary;
namespace ReflectionSecurityTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo f = new Foo();
            var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            var field = f.GetType().GetField("X", flags);
            field.SetValue(f,15);
            Console.WriteLine(field.GetValue(f));
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect to see an exception but instead I see `15` in the Console.The question is **why** ? Did I misunderstand what `SecurityCritical` does or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bullet point below that states:

> - Code that is running with **partial trust** is treated as transparent.
>
> **Application code that is run from the command line runs with full trust.** As long as it is not marked as transparent, it can use reflection to access security-critical members. When the same code is run with partial trust (for example, in a sandboxed application domain) the assembly's trust level determines whether it can access security-critical code: If the assembly has a strong name and is installed in the global assembly cache, it is a trusted assembly and can call security-critical members. If it is not trusted, it becomes transparent even though it was not marked as transparent, and it cannot access security-critical members.

So to answer the question from your title:

> How can I avoid accessing private members of a class using Reflection?

You can't, if you can't sandbox the code performing the reflection.

Comment: you're right. but I wish we could do that,the reflection is cool and realy useful in most cases but it also breaks all the rules of language.

Comment: You have to accept that anything that is run by a PC will at some moment be in a piece of memory that is inspectable by other processes. If you want to hide your implementation, take a look at obfuscation and the likes. It's usually not worth the effort, though. If you really have some unique algorithm you absolutely never want any eyes on, run it on a server you control and let the users send it parameters.